# SPI library installation error

Tags: raspbian, gpio, spi

I want to read and write RC522 RFID by using raspberry pi. For that I want configure SPI communication. First I enable SPI in raspi.config. After that I tried to download SPI-Py package to enable SPI communication for Python from this link https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py. I already update python and python 3 by using this command;

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev and python3-dev
```

I use this commands;

```
git clone https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py
```

and install it via

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

This SPI-Py folder is in /home/pi directory.

Then this error came.

```
raspberrypi root @: ~ # cd / home / pi / SPI-py   
raspberrypi root @ :/ home / pi / SPI-py # sudo python setup.py install   
running install   
running build   
running build_ext  
building 'spiritual' extension  
gcc-pthread-fno-strict-aliasing-DNDEBUG-g-fwrapv-O2-Wall-Wstrict-prototypes-fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7-c-o spi.c build/temp.linux-armv6l- 2.7/spi.o  
spi.c: 20:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.  
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: on line that says
`gcc-pthread-fno-strict-aliasing-DNDEBUG-g-fwrapv-O2-Wall-Wstrict-prototypes-fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7-c-o spi.c build/temp.linux-armv6l- 2.7/spi.o` I noticed there is no spaces between arguments (as in between python2.7 and the following -c and so on). Is this a formatting problem on your question or does it appears the same way on your machine ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Python development environment (part of the environment is the missing python.h).

For Python 2: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

For Python 3: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: I installed both of these but same problem. I found the solution of it I already put on comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to install Python 2.7. Please try the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Comment: Python2.7 is already the  newest version. python2.7 set to manually installed. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 129 not upgraded.  This is the massage. But same problem.

Comment: OK. Can you try compiling this SPI library: https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev. This works for me.

Comment: running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/spidev.so -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spidev.so: Permission denied

Comment: Please try it with "sudo"

Comment: git clone  github.com/doceme/py-spidev and sudo python setup.py install  this is what i tried. is it wrong ?

Comment: yes, it should be git clone https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev.git

Comment: running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/spidev.so -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spidev.so: Permission denied

Comment: same error coming

Comment: Seems like you don't have SPI enabled. Please follow this tutorial: https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/spi-raspbian-wheezy/info.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried this http://geraintw.blogspot.com/2014/01/rfid-and-raspberry-pi.html Its work for me.

```
> sudo apt-get install python-dev git clone
> https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git
> cd SPI-Py sudo python setup.py
> install
```

Comment: It could be nice to include the essential parts of the link (that could becomes unreachable) in your answer